# Cassandra query with consistency failure

Tags: cassandra

I have this following table:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.customer_data (
    field1 int,
    field2 int,
    field3 int,
    field4 text,
    field5 text,
    data_time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((field1, field2, field3, field4, field5), data_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (utilisation_time ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

I have script to collect the daily data as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.customer_data WHERE field1 = 21 AND 
  data_time >= '2020-03-26 16:00:00' AND 
  data_time <= '2020-03-27 15:59:00' ALLOW FILTERING
```

Almost all days can queried without problems, except one specific day, which I believe has very large data than the other.

the client side (in java) get this error message:

```
Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
```

In the system.log, i capture this log when the client app hit the query:

```
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,029 MessagingService.java:1236 - READ messages were dropped in last 5000 ms: 1 internal and 0 cross node. Mean internal dropped latency: 5960 ms and Mean cross-node dropped latency: 0 ms
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,029 StatusLogger.java:47 - Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,033 StatusLogger.java:51 - MutationStage                     0         0     2273404011         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,033 StatusLogger.java:51 - ViewMutationStage                 0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,033 StatusLogger.java:51 - ReadStage                         0         0       55205177         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,033 StatusLogger.java:51 - RequestResponseStage              0         0     3551921449         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,033 StatusLogger.java:51 - ReadRepairStage                   0         0        1016339         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,034 StatusLogger.java:51 - CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,034 StatusLogger.java:51 - MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,034 StatusLogger.java:51 - CompactionExecutor                0         0       19952206         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,034 StatusLogger.java:51 - MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0          22014         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,034 StatusLogger.java:51 - PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              8         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,035 StatusLogger.java:51 - GossipStage                       0         0       75343472         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,035 StatusLogger.java:51 - SecondaryIndexManagement          0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,035 StatusLogger.java:51 - HintsDispatcher                   0         0            681         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,035 StatusLogger.java:51 - MigrationStage                    0         0            108         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,035 StatusLogger.java:51 - MemtablePostFlush                 0         0          22759         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,035 StatusLogger.java:51 - PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0         0         0          22006         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,036 StatusLogger.java:51 - ValidationExecutor                0         0            392         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,036 StatusLogger.java:51 - Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,036 StatusLogger.java:51 - MemtableFlushWriter               0         0          22014         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,036 StatusLogger.java:51 - InternalResponseStage             0         0         421680         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,036 StatusLogger.java:51 - AntiEntropyStage                  0         0           1104         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,036 StatusLogger.java:51 - CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:51 - Native-Transport-Requests         0         0     1619401305         0             19514

INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:61 - CompactionManager                 0         0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:73 - MessagingService                n/a       0/0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:83 - Cache Type                     Size                 Capacity               KeysToSave
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:85 - KeyCache                   99614696                 99614720                      all
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:91 - RowCache                          0                        0                      all
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:98 - Table                                     Memtable ops,data
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_distributed.parent_repair_history  0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_distributed.repair_history         0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_distributed.view_build_status      0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.compaction_history                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,037 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.schema_aggregates                  0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.schema_triggers                    0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.size_estimates                     0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.paxos                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.views_builds_in_progress           0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.batches                            0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.schema_keyspaces                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.sstable_activity                   39,2699
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.batchlog                           0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.schema_columns                     0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.hints                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.IndexInfo                          0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.schema_columnfamilies              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.schema_functions                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.built_views                        0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,038 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.peer_events                        0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.range_xfers                        0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.peers                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.transferred_ranges                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.schema_usertypes                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.local                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.available_ranges                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - system.prepared_statements                0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.customer_data                        30776,2714968
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table1                               296603,12546709
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table2                               26825,4419610
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table3                               0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table4                               3,236
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table5                               63,4990
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table6                               0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table7                               3,363
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,039 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table8                               0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table9                               4,108
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table10                              2,70
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table11                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table12                              35,1583
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table13                              7920,790982
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table14                              123,7473
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table15                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table16                              0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table17                              18638,3336186
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table18                              9254,1443624
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - mydb.table19                              3,69
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.columns                     0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.types                       0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,040 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.indexes                     0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.keyspaces                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.dropped_columns                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.aggregates                  0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.triggers                    0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.tables                      0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.views                       0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_schema.functions                   0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_auth.roles                         0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_auth.role_members                  0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_auth.resource_role_permissons_index                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_auth.role_permissions                 0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_traces.sessions                    0,0
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 StatusLogger.java:101 - system_traces.events                      0,0
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-04-03 05:07:59,041 MonitoringTask.java:152 - 1 operations timed out in the last 5017 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM mydb.customer_data WHERE field1 = 21 AND data_time >= 2020-03-26 16:00Z AND data_time <= 2020-03-27 15:59Z LIMIT 5000>, total time 5004 msec, timeout 5000 msec
```

This is `nodetool tablestats` of table `mydb.customer_data` in one of the node:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-227:/usr/local/cassandra/conf$ /usr/local/cassandra/bin/nodetool tablestats prospacedb.quarter_utilisation
Total number of tables: 56
----------------
Keyspace : mydb
    Read Count: 5282126
    Read Latency: 2.48710102428454 ms
    Write Count: 2164892217
    Write Latency: 0.016614636464832373 ms
    Pending Flushes: 0
        Table: customer_data
        SSTable count: 15
        Space used (live): 2455268488
        Space used (total): 2455268488
        Space used by snapshots (total): 3241990632
        Off heap memory used (total): 1019317
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.3615507660944151
        Number of partitions (estimate): 14732
        Memtable cell count: 86273
        Memtable data size: 7612904
        Memtable off heap memory used: 0
        Memtable switch count: 1664
        Local read count: 592956
        Local read latency: NaN ms
        Local write count: 278088230
        Local write latency: NaN ms
        Pending flushes: 0
        Percent repaired: 76.49
        Bloom filter false positives: 0
        Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
        Bloom filter space used: 145840
        Bloom filter off heap memory used: 145720
        Index summary off heap memory used: 47685
        Compression metadata off heap memory used: 825912
        Compacted partition minimum bytes: 87
        Compacted partition maximum bytes: 1131752
        Compacted partition mean bytes: 63353
        Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): NaN
        Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
        Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): NaN
        Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
        Dropped Mutations: 0
```

What is the potential root cause that makes this problem? Is there any quick solution to make the query running?

Comment: As the saying goes "If you're using ALLOW FILTERING, you're doing it wrong."  Alex's answer is spot-on.  Taking a look at the free learning material offered by DataStax will help you get this on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major reason why this query fails is that it's incorrect - Cassandra works fast only when you have full partition key, and then you can do the range query inside that partition.  In your case, you have partition key consisting of 5 columns, but you're providing only one in the query, and Cassandra needs to perform scanning of the whole data to find where the corresponding rows are located.  I really wondering that it worked before...

To solve your problem you need to change the table structure to have partition/primary key matching your queries - all data modeling for Cassandra starts with queries that should be executed. I recommend to take [DS220 course at DataStax Academy on data modelling](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220).